# Passing String value from One Async task to another

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have 2 `AsyncTask` , `AsyncOne` and `AsyncTwo`.
In First AsyncTask background method i am getting a string value and setting that in `onpostexecute`.,

like this `item = i.getname();`

here `item` is a global variable.

Now i am setting this item value is `onpostexecute` method of AsyncTwo but i get null there ?

How to get the item value?

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is right with your code and global variable stuff,just make sure that your both asyncTask shouldn't be in running mode simultaneously.Start second task in first's postExecute().

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure asynctask 1 is finished when you start async task 2. You can keep item as a field in asynctask 1, than can call publishProgress when you can set the value, and start asynctask 2 in task 1's `onProgressUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds you have two concurrent tasks running in the background, and **task2** depends on the result of **task1**. Since they are running concurrently, **task2** may finish before **task1** does, so there's no guarantee that when **task2** finishes, it will get the result of **task1**.

To ensure that you can run two tasks concurrently, you can synchronize the `doInBackround()` method of **task1**, and offer a synchronized `getItem()` method in **task1**:

```
// in task1
private Object item; // instance variable to be set in doInBackground
protected synchronized Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
    // set item to some value here
    item = ...;
}
public synchronized Object getItem () {
    return item;
}


// in task2
protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
    // do work of task2
    ....

    // when finishing our work, ready to get the result of task1.
    // we don't call task1.getItem() in onPostExecute() to avoid possibly blocking the UI thread
    Object item = task1.getItem();
    // pass item to the onPostExecute method
}
```

With the above code, **task2** will wait for **task1** to finish and get the result if it runs faster than **task1**.